# Quiz Development on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am a high school student developing an app for the SAT. Some questions will have answer choices that have only text, but some questions have answer choices that only have images. How would I solve this issue? I don't want to create an activity for each question.

Thank You so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a tour of [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask such a general question. If you have a specific technical question then Stackoverflow is your friend, but you won't get an answer for a general question like this. Try reading some books or tutorials or search for solutions to similar problems. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Design Support library.

The Design support library was created to facilitate the creation of applications that use components and behaviors characteristic of Material Design in a way compatible with versions of Android 2.1 and higher (API 7+). With it we can use components like Snackbar or FAB without having to worry (a lot) about users in older versions of Android because all the work has already been done by Google.